# Mysql - Ordering Episodes Correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a movie database (copyright-free :)). What I want to do is ordering episodes by title.

I am using relevancy algorithms but they can be equal so as a last method If everything is equal, I want to sorth them by title.

Example Titles:

```
title
XXX Season 1 Episode 1
XXX Season 1 Episode 10
XXX Season 1 Episode 2
XXX Season 2 Episode 4
XXX Season 2 Episode 1
XXX Season 2 Episode 16
```

I tried `ORDER BY cast(title as UNSIGNED) asc` but it didnt work at all.

Expected Result;

```
title
XXX Season 1 Episode 1
XXX Season 1 Episode 2
XXX Season 1 Episode 10
XXX Season 2 Episode 1
XXX Season 2 Episode 4
XXX Season 2 Episode 16
```

Which method could I use to achieve this? The titles will not be in some sort of template, they can vary like the following examples;

```
XXX S1E4
XXX 2. Ep
XXX Ep 5. Season 7 etc...
```

Since I have other relevancy algorithms, it will sort them relevancy based, I mean `XXX S1E4` wont have same relevancy point with `XXX 2. Ep`, but it will have same relevancy point with `XXX S2E8`

Comment: I think you know the answer to this.

Comment: Well, the answer is, fix your data. Store the season number in a separate column, store the episode number in a separate column. Databases in general are not built for text processing.

Comment: There's no good way to do this without somehow splitting the episode number out of that string, so that you can sort the numbers numerically. Assuming there's no consistent format of the titles, what would you expect if the second example in your list had the title "XXX Season One Episode Ten"?

Comment: I guess you _could_ try something like padding any numbers you find with a fixed number of leading zeroes, which will make most cases sort alphabetically as you expect, but then how will you deal with '2001: A Space Odyssey' or 'Se7en'?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave That doesn't fix it, when the to be casted string starts with a character. It will simply be casted to 0.

Comment: @fancyPants, I'm not sure I understand your point. I didn't mention casting anywhere. But more importantly, I'm not disagreeing with you - as I said "there's no good way to do this" - my second comment is simply offering a possible (but very sub-optimal) approach, hence the word "could" being italicised.